# SocketTimeoutException occurs frequently in ICS Sony Xperia

Tags: android

The application that I have created, an exception is raised frequently in the Xperia Active and Xperia SX. (There are ICS 4.0.4 device).

```
09-07 13:11:56.755: W/System.err(2012): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
09-07 13:11:56.765: W/System.err(2012):           at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:544)
09-07 13:11:56.775: W/System.err(2012):           at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:791)
09-07 13:11:56.775: W/System.err(2012):           at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
09-07 13:11:56.775: W/System.err(2012):           at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475)
```

---

The application is very simple using the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.connect();
    String responseMessage = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    final String contentType = connection.getContentType();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
    in.close;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

You can not be an exception occurs on the ICS devices from other vendors.
I do not think the problem of the application.
Is there no workaround or something?

Comment: Mmm...

Main: Video Example Shows ICS and WiFi Connectivity Issue http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/37014?tstart=0
Main: Wi-Fi problems? Look here first. http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/31449

This problem has occurred in WiFi connection. 
These obstacles may be the causes of the problem.